# Set global:false for specific Ajax.Helper in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to set the gobal: false like in an jquery ajax call for just one specific Ajax.BeginForm event without messing up the global ajax event handlers (like ajaxSend or ajaxComplete) for other ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid not. Global event handling is not a parameter you can pass with the Ajax helpers. You can view the list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions_properties.aspx).

If you wish to use global handling for a specific AJAX call you can use it through

```
$.ajax({
   /* Ajax-y goodness */
   global: false
 });
```

And if you wish to disable all globals for all calls on the page:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    global: false
});
```

Although better practice is to handle each event seperately:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    console.log('Leeerrooooyyyy Jennnnkiiiiins');
});
```